# WPF-MVVM: Handeling Event from within DataGrid Style

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I develop Prism+MEF application based on WPF+MVVM, where there are many DataGrids so i build DataGridStyle to be applied for all DataGrids in all modules. The style add Filter Text Box in the Columns Headers, and i used MVVM Light EventToCommand to trigger TextChanged event when the Text Box text is changed like this: (this code exist in DataGridStyle Resource Dictionary)

```
    <TextBox x:Name="filterTextBox" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="25" Height="Auto"
         OpacityMask="Black" Visibility="Collapsed" 
         Text=""
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.TextChangedCommand}"
                          PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </TextBox>
```

Then i handled the TextChangedCommand in ViewModel (pertaining to View that contains the Data Grid)using Attached property:

```
#region TextChangedCommand----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        static ICommand command; //1

        public static ICommand GetTextChangedCommand(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTextChangedCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextChangedCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextChangedCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TextChangedCommand",
                                                 typeof(ICommand), 
                                                 typeof(SubsystemAllViewModel),
                                                 new UIPropertyMetadata(null, CommandChanged));


        static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fe = obj as FrameworkElement;
            command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            fe.AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(ExecuteCommand));
        }

        static void ExecuteCommand(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Some  Code
        }


        #endregion
```

And the View that contains the Grid:

```
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Subsystems,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSubsystem, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
                   Name="SubsystemAllDataGrid"              
                   Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
                   Grid.Row="2">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial" Binding="{Binding Path=Serial, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="System" Binding="{Binding Path=System, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SubsystemNo"  Binding="{Binding Path=SubsystemNo, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scope" Binding="{Binding Path=Scope, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" Binding="{Binding Path=Area, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Priority" Binding="{Binding Path=Priority, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DossierLocation" Binding="{Binding Path=DossierLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parts" Binding="{Binding Path=Parts, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="StatusDate" Binding="{Binding Path=StatusDate, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MCDate" Binding="{Binding Path=MCDate, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PlnMCDate" Binding="{Binding Path=PlnMCDate, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remark" Binding="{Binding Path=Remark, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

The problems are:
When i enter filter text in the text box in one of the columns headers of the data grid nothing happen and break points at following points not hit:

1-GetTextChangedCommand and SetTextChangedCommand

2-The CommandChanged() method.

i'm new to wpf so i'm sure there are faults in WPF or C# code..., so please help me fixing these faults.

Note: i don't use code behind.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to be a MVVM-light specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Command-Binding doesnt work. Try the following:

```
Command="{Binding Path=TextChangedCommand}"
```

or

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}} Path=DataContext.TextChangedCommand}"
```

Comment: i applied the two options but still nothing happen when i enter filter text in the filter text box in any of the columns header.

Comment: Why dont you bind the Text property of the TextBox to a property in your ViewModel. So you could call the TextChangedCommand in the setter of this property.

Comment: i tried doing this but i have two problems, the first one: the getter is called but the setter never called i don't know why. The second proble: i need to use EventToCommand to pass the event arguments to the View Model

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints not hit makes me thing binding issue.

The datacontext for you command needs to be set to where your command is defined.  SO if your command is defined in your viewmodel, you need to use the following but set the ansestor type to the type of object that binds to your viewmodel.  This is usually your view, not the datagrid:

```
 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewType}} Path=DataContext.TextChangedCommand}"
```

So if your view is a window or user control then change the ViewType to the respective type.

You can also see if there are any binding errors generated for your command in the output window when you run your app.

**EDIT 1:**
Don't use dependency property, use relay command from MVVM-Light in your view model:

```
 this.YourRelayCommand = new RelayCommand( ExecuteYourCommand, CanYourCommandExecute);

  public RelayCommand YourRelayCommand{ get; private set; }

  public bool CanYourCommandExecute() {

    }

  public void ExecuteYourCommand() {
    //TODO: Do code here 
    }
```

Comment: @J King : still nothing happen when i enter text in the filter text box. by the way i inserted a break point at the Attached property RegisterAttached statement which is hit when the View is opening.

Comment: can you post the whole xaml where your view and datagrid are defined.  Did you get any binding errors in your output window?

Comment: Also, if you are using MVVM-Light, why are you not using the relay command that is designed for this purpose?

Comment: @J King : the whole xaml for my view is divided into 3 parts the first part contains buttons for adding rows, deleting rows, ... etc and the second part for the grid which i included in my question and the third part is a footer.

Comment: @J King : The DataContext is set in the code behind of the view because i use MEF (Microsoft Extensibility Framework) and i don't get binding errors in my output window. and i have to use MVVM-Light to enable me to fire event from within the DataGrid style and without using code behind.

Comment: @J King : i also have to use MVVM-Light because i need to pass the event arguments to the view model

Comment: Again, I need to see your code. Please edit your question to include the xaml for your view and the code behind where you set your data context